# How do i stop AWS from billing me more when i do not have active EC2 and RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I do not have active instances neither do i have active RDS but on my dashboard, i keep seeing multiples of bills coming through EC2 and RDS. How do i prevent further bills?

WHAT I HAVE DONE: I have tried stopping all active instances but there is no active instance. there is also no active RDS.
My sole aim is to stop further bills since there is no activity on my aws platform

Comment: Take a look at your bill, make sure everything is really gone: https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home#/bills

Comment: You probably have RDS snapshots, or EBS volumes left over from your EC2 instances, or maybe EBS snapshots or AMIs. Or you may have things in other regions that you still need to delete (the bill will indicate the region).

Answer (score 0):

My next steps in solving that problem would be:

- review current and previous [bills in the dashboard](https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home#/bills)

  - use the `Charges by service` tab to verify all other regions available in that account and verify that no other EC2 or RDS resources exist there
  - if this account is a root or billing account in an [aws organization](https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/iamv2/home?region=us-east-1#/organization/accounts), use the `Charges by account` tab to verify that all child accounts do not have the unexpected resources in any available region
- contact [aws support](https://support.console.aws.amazon.com/support/home#/case/create) with a priority billing -> charge inquiry support request

#### charges by account

[image: aws billing dashboard]